# Drawing line in flash- via Action script

Tags: apache-flex, graphics

I need to draw a line in ActionScript(based on calculated conditions for length and rotation)

I tried the following code- the triangle with the fill appears- but not the line with the lineStyle- Could you pls help me out on this... c is defined as UIComponent

```
var myShape:Shape=new Shape();  
myShape.graphics.moveTo(100,100);  
myShape.graphics.lineTo(200,200);  
myShape.graphics.lineStyle(2,0xFF0000,.75);  
c.addChild(myShape);                

var triangleHeight:uint = 100;  
var triangle:Shape = new Shape();
// red triangle
triangle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);  
triangle.graphics.moveTo(triangleHeight/2, 200);  
triangle.graphics.lineTo(triangleHeight, triangleHeight);  
triangle.graphics.lineTo(0, triangleHeight);  
triangle.graphics.lineTo(triangleHeight/2, 200);  
c.addChild(triangle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare line style before your drawing.

Comment: Thanks- silly miss... another quick question- it seems to take about 2 seconds to render- is that normal? Will it get extra slow if I have around 15-20 lines drawn?

Comment: No6 it isn't normal. It should render very smooth without any visible delay. And you can draw a lot of lines without any problem. It seems the drawing code executes more than one time per frame. Try to set `trace()` in your code and check how often it is called.